# Should I use quotes or colons for session keys in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a session variable that returns the same value when I use both `session["test"]` or `session[:test]`.  Are these two the same? Is it better to use one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a standard Ruby Hash they're not the same ([string vs symbol](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/))

However, the rails [`SessionHash`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L50) subclass calls `to_s` on the keys before storing them, so all keys are stored as strings (even if you specify a symbol):

```
class SessionHash < Hash

  def [](key)
    load_for_read!
    super(key.to_s)
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    load_for_write!
    super(key.to_s, value)
  end
```

That's why `session[:test]` and `session["test"]` will return the same value in rails.

Comment: The basic problem is that you don't want to convert tained Strings to Symbols, because Symbols don't get garbage-collected.

Comment: one thing I noticed today. My session values are accessible by strings not symbols keys. While params are working with symbols too. I'm using  ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.13

Comment: The `string vs symbol` link is broken : /

Answer (score 1):

As far as ruby string and symbols go they are not the same.

As a general rule, you should use the second form, a symbol is something used to represent something which would otherwise be a string. It is a way to efficiently have descriptive names while saving the space you would use to generate a string multiple times.

This means that you do not create a new instance each time you refer to the symbol as you would a string. The symbol is simply a better way to represent the value you are describing.

Just for completeness, I should mention a symbol can trivially be converted to a string if you need a representation later.

if you want to read more there is a lengthy blog post [just here](http://aaronbonner.tumblr.com/post/5960999188/understanding-ruby-symbols) which explains ruby symbols well. Suffice to say they are an optimisation.

That said ruby SessionHash calls to_s on symbols so you can use either in this case as a string will result from the input either way.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't precisely the same. They're two ways of accomplishing the same thing.

In general, in Ruby a major use of symbols is as keys. Symbols are `:these_things`. Hash keys are a typical use for them...

```
{
  :name => 'Mary',
  :rank => 'Captain'
}
```

Session keys are also usually symbols.

Using Strings instead won't hurt anything, but symbols are more typical.